# Is it possible to create a generic type to use in another types?

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
function stackPlayer(stack){

}
```

The `stack` parameter can only be one of the following:

1. a function that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments.
2. a function that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments, and returns a function that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments.
3. a function that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments, and returns an array of functions that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments.
4. an array of functions that takes `req`, `res`, `next` as arguments.

#### Practical example:

```js
// the following is allowed to used as an argument:
(req, res, next) => {} // or
(req, res, next) => (req, res, next) => {} // or
(req,res,sNext) => [(req,res,sNext)=>{}] // or
[(req,res,sNext)=>{}]
```

In order to type the parameter of the function, I wrote the following, which looks quite complex to read and understand:

```
type Stack =
  | ((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {})
  | ((
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      next: NextFunction
    ) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {})
  | ((
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      next: NextFunction
    ) => { (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void }[])
  | { (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void }[]

function stackPlayer(stack: Stack){

}
```

How can I simplify this long long type? can I create a generic type and use it for another type, ex:

```
type Smiddleware = <T = void>(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => T
type Stack = Smiddleware<void> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware[]> | Smiddleware[]
```

This looks much better, but it's of course not valid.

Comment: Can you try using this definition? `type Smiddleware<T = void> = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => T` maybe it'll work. In the current definition the generic `T` corresponds to the function instead of being a type argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the generic parameter to the `Smiddleware` type instead of the function inside.

Something like this:

```
type Smiddleware<T> = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => T
type Stack = Smiddleware<{}> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware<{}>> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware<void>[]> | Smiddleware<void>[]
```

Then you can use other type instead of `{}` or `void`, depending on what the function returns.

For example:

```
type Stack = Smiddleware<{}> | Smiddleware<number> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware<string>>;
```

Regarding your question on the comment, if you want to be able to use `Smiddleware` without specifying the type, you can add a default value for the generic parameter:

```
type Smiddleware<T = void> = ... // same as before
```

Comment: What does `Smiddleware<{}>` mean?

Comment: Can I write `type Stack = Smiddleware<void> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware> | Smiddleware<Smiddleware[]> | Smiddleware[]` ? Is it valid?

Comment: `Smiddleware<{}>` is the equivalent of `Smiddleware<object>`. I just used it because it is was you had on the `Stack` definition in your question. You can use other type instead.

Comment: yes, ok. And what's the difference when using the angle brackets `<>` before the function, and after the type alias? `type Smiddleware<T> = ` and `type Smiddleware = <T>(x, y, z) => T`

Comment: The second type allow you to declare a variable of this type, and defer the generic parameter to when the variable is used, whereas for the first you need to specify the generic parameter when declaring the variable. Not easy to explain, but see [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEDl0HEIIQBOqSUAvFADwAqAfABQCGRA5gM4BcUNAlBXR4BuAFChIsRCgwJ8hEklqDKzNlx79ygmqJFJM7YFABmUnHOKlu8ZGkzmClsipatNg16P0JDUJgGVgEgRWChMzPEcFBgAiAFsQQ2DWGN4vAyMmACF0dAAbCCYEMNNkB3lSBiC4CDSRPQzw5AsFayk7WSjSKiTUEOUoVTcBPzZ0n0zA5IAJYmhKUqQWypimdjXUkSA)

Comment: cool, but they serve the same purpose right?